# Accepting unicode filenames as arguments in Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, qt-creator, qt5

I am trying to pass a Unicode file-name `Myfile 1 абв.jpg` as an argument (`QString fileTitle = args.at(4);`) to a Qt5 GUI app in windows but Unicode characters are getting converted to `???` (`Myfile 1 ???.jpg`) and results in error `Error opening save file` with following code:

The code used to save file is :

```
if(!m_file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        qDebug() << tr("Error opening save file");
        abort();
    }
```

Comment: This happens because int main(int argc, char *argv[]) works with not Unicode characters by default in qt application

Comment: Do you get `args` from `QApplication::arguments`? It should process unicode characters correctly. There can be another error with file writing (e.g. no write access), so check `m_file->errorString()` just in case. Also the problem may be in the way you're starting the app (if you use arguments option in Qt Creator, it theoretically may encode it incorrectly). Try to pass the argument manually in command line.